# sort on pipe-delimited fields not behaving as expected

Tags: sorting, unix, sh

Consider this tiny text file:

```
ab
a
```

If we run it through sort(1), we get

```
a
ab
```

because of course `a` comes before `ab`.

But now consider this file:

```
ab|c
a|c
```

If we run it through `sort -t'|'`, we again expect `a` to sort before `ab`, but it does not!  (Try it under your version of Unix and see.)

What I think is happening here is that the `-t` option to `sort` is not *really* delimiting fields -- it may be changing the way (say) the start of field 2 would be found, but it's not changing the way field 1 *ends*.  `a|c` sorts after `ab|c` because `'|'` comes after `'b'` in ASCII.  (It's as if the `-t'|'` argument is ignored, because you get the same result without it.)

So is this a bug in `sort` or in my understanding of it?  And is there a way to sort on the first pipe-delimited field properly?

This question came up in my attempt to answer another SO question, [Join Statement omitting entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894105/join-statement-omitting-entries) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort`'s default behavior is to treat everything from field 1 to the end of the line as the sort key. If you want it to sort on field 1 first, then field 2, you need to specify that explicitly.

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -t'|' <<< $'ab|c\na|c'
a|c
ab|c
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  I want to sort on just column 1, and I tried `-k1`, but what I need, as you suggest, is `-k1,1`.  Thanks for the prompt response!