# Unix command to add field from file1 to matching keyed record in file1

Tags: unix

I have limited coding skills in Unix so I am asking for help.

I have 2 files coming in:

file1:

column names

Key      Count

```
68150    500
68220    300
68448    200
68778    500
```

file2:

```
68150    53
68171     6
68448    18
68778    05
68993    13
```

What I need is:
1 - A single record for all of the unique keys between the 2 files.
2 - Where the key matches the Count fields are added together.

Output file:

```
68150    553
68171      6
68220    300
68448    215
68778    505
68993    13
```

I have looked a the 'join' 'comm' 'diff' and 'sort' commands and they don't appear to be what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, this should work (assuming the input files are `/tmp/file1` and `/tmp/file2`)

```
join -a 1 -a 2 <(sort -b /tmp/file1) <(sort -b /tmp/file2) | while read a b c; do
    echo $a $((${b:-0} + ${c:-0}))
done
```

Let me explain it step by step:

First, we have to join the lines (and by passing `-a 1 -a 2` not dropping any unmatched records)

```
$ join -a 1 -a 2 <(sort -b /tmp/file1) <(sort -b /tmp/file2)
68150 500 53
68171 6
68220 300
68448 200 18
68778 500 05
68993 13
```

Then, we can just read everything line by line using `read a b c`, so the first column will be in `$a`, the second in `$b` and the third in `$c`. The last problem we have to solve is that it might only have two and not three columns, but that's easy in bash: `${c:-0}` will evaluate to `$c` if non-empty and have a default value of `0` otherwise.

Oh, and using `$(( expr ))` we can do computations. Final output:

```
$ join -a 1 -a 2 <(sort -b /tmp/file1) <(sort -b /tmp/file2) | while read a b c; do echo $a $((${b:-0} + ${c:-0})); done
68150 553
68171 6
68220 300
68448 218
68778 505
68993 13
```

Comment: I don't believe `join` will work if the files are sorted numerically.  I'd drop the `-n` from the `sort` invocations.

Comment: hi @SteveSummit, I believe it will work with both as the important thing is that lines are sorted similarly in both files. That's both true for `-n` and non `-n`. But `-n` is certainly not necessary so I dropped it :).

Comment: Well, we had terrible problems with that over at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894105/join-statement-omitting-entries/).  If the numbers are such that numeric verus alphabetic sorting gives different answers (think 10, 20, 101), join misses some of the joins, because it always assumes alphabetical sorting.

Comment: yes, so the `join`  man page does in fact mention we should use the `-b` option. So I'll change the answer accordingly.